# CheckBox state is not updated after click in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, checkbox, checked

I have a list of CheckBoxes and after clicking on them the state is not updated. 
Why is this happening and how can I repair this?

```
            private List<CheckBox> blocks_check_boxes = new List<CheckBox>();

            count = blocks_from_database.Count;
            /* Display check boxes for each block*/
            for (int i = 0; i < blocks_from_database.Count; i++)
            {
                blocks_check_boxes.Add(new CheckBox());
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].AutoSize = true;

                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].Name = blocks_from_database[i].name;
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].TabIndex = 3 + i;
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].Text = blocks_from_database[i].name;
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.blocks_check_boxes[i].AutoCheck = true;


            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Would it maybe make more sense to use a `CheckedListBox` for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are recreating the CheckBoxes in an unwanted way.

Maybe you want to set the "AutoPostBack" property till "true".

It's pretty hard to understand what's causing your problem when we don't see more code. Explain a little more when you are detecting your problem and also where and when your code above is executing.

Comment: After creating this list I mark some of the elements as checked.

Comment: foreach (CheckBox box in blocks_check_boxes)
       if (box.Name.Trim() == line.Trim())
            box.Checked = true;

Comment: After that I used it only after the user has the chance to check the boxes and presses a button.After the pressing of the button I write  all checked items in a file, and here is where the problem appears, because the boxes that have checked value are the ones that I checked using the code above.

Comment: Okay, I would guess that you are setting the checkboxes states once again after pressing the button but before the "Button1_Click" function runs. That would be the case if you are doing it in the Page_Load event. Set a breakpoint where you set your checkboxes values and one in Button1_Click to se which occour first.

Comment: I set a breakpoint where I set the checkboxes and it executes only once before I press the button. it is like clicking on the checkboxes has no effect. Maybe I have to make some settings from properties.. or I don't know..